# Image resizer and uploader

Tags: php, image, network-file-transfer

I've written an image resizer / uploader, that takes an incoming image, resizes it, and uploads it to the server, under the `/usericons/` folder.

However, the code is sloppy. Can somebody suggest a better method / improvements?

```
define ("MAX_SIZE","400");

$errors = 0;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $image = $_FILES["icon"]["name"];
  $uploadedfile = $_FILES['icon']['tmp_name'];
  if ($image) {
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['icon']['name']);
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
        if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) {
              echo ' Unknown Image extension ';
              $errors = 1;
        } else {
              $size=filesize($_FILES['icon']['tmp_name']);
              if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024) {
                    echo "You have exceeded the size limit";
                    $errors = 1;
              }
              if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension == "jpeg" ) {
                    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['icon']['tmp_name'];
                    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
              } else if($extension=="png") {
                    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['icon']['tmp_name'];
                    $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
              } else {
                    $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
              }
              list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);
              $newwidth = 500;
              $newheight = ($height/$width)*$newwidth;
              $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
              $newwidth1 = 300;
              $newheight1 = ($height/$width)*$newwidth1;
              $tmp1 = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);
              imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
              imagecopyresampled($tmp1, $src, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth1, $newheight1, $width, $height);
              $filename = "usericons/500-". $_SESSION['username'] . '.png';
              $filename1 = "usericons/300-". $_SESSION['username'] . '.png';
              imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
              imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);
              hasIcon($_SESSION['username']);
              imagedestroy($src);
              imagedestroy($tmp);
              imagedestroy($tmp1);
              echo '<script>window.location = "/Users/";</script>';
        }
  }
}
 //If no errors registred, print the success message

if (isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) {
   echo "Image Upload Fail!";
}
function getExtension($str) {

     $i = strrpos($str,".");
     if (!$i) { return ""; } 
     $l = strlen($str) - $i;
     $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
     return $ext;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things I've done to your code:

- Early exits
- Redundant code removal
- Readability improvement

Keep in mind that I have *not* tested this, but it should work. And also, the code will only work on PHP 5.4 and greater.

**Cleaned up version**:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST' || !isset($_FILES['icon'])) {
    echo 'Image upload failed.';

    return;
}

$file = [
    'name' => stripslashes($_FILES['icon']['name']),
    'path' => $_FILES['icon']['tmp_name'],
    'ext'  => strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['icon']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)),
    'size' => filesize($_FILES['icon']['tmp_name'])
];

$supportedExts = [
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png',
    'gif'
];

if (!in_array($file['ext'], $supportedExts)) {
    echo 'Extension not supported.';

    return;
}

if ($file['size'] > 400 * 1024) {
    echo 'You have exceeded the image size limit.';

    return;
}

list($image['x'], $image['y']) = getimagesize($file['path']);

switch ($file['ext']) {
    case 'jpg':
    case 'jpeg':
        $imgResrc1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['path']);
        break;
    case 'png':
        $imgResrc1 = imagecreatefrompng($file['path']);
        break;
    default:
        $imgResrc1 = imagecreatefromgif($file['path']);
}

$imageSizes = array(
    [
        'x' => 300,
        'y' => $image['y'] / $image['x'] * 300
    ],
    [
        'x' => 500,
        'y' => $image['y'] / $image['x'] * 500
    ]
);

foreach ($imageSizes as $size) {
    $imgResrc2 = imagecreatetruecolor($size['x'], $size['y']);

    imagecopyresampled($imgResrc2, $imgResrc1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $size['x'], $size['y'], $image['x'], $image['y']);

    // Shouldn't the extension be .jpg / .jpeg since you're using imagejpeg()?
    $filePath = 'usericons/' . $size['x'] . '-'. $_SESSION['username'] . '.png';

    imagejpeg($imgResrc2, $filePath, 100);

    imagedestroy($imgResrc2);
}

imagedestroy($imgResrc1);

hasIcon($_SESSION['username']);

echo '<script>window.location = \'/Users/\';</script>';

// TODO: Print success message
```

Answer (score 1):

#### function getExtension() replacement

you can replace it with this code

```
$filename = stripslashes($_FILES['icon']['name']);
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

so you can safely remove `function getExtension()` because you don't need it anymore.